# Underscore as a segment_separators in routing.yml

Tags: routes, symfony1

In symfony project, I would like to use an underscore as a separator
for the parameter in routing.yml.

Url example:
/article/lorem-1111_45.html

In routing.yml

```
rule_sample:
 url:      /article/:info-:datePublished_:id.html
 param:    { module: cms, action: test }
 options:
   segment_separators: ['-', '/', '.', '_']
 requirements:
   info: ^([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$
   datePublished: \d+
   id: \d+
```

This code doesnt work. I have the following error:
Unable to parse "/article/:info-:datePublished_:id.html" route near
":id.html".

Anybody knows how to implement this rule ?

Comment: +1: I was never able to get this satisfactorily myself, would be interested in a solution. Do note however that dashes (-) are considered more SEO-friendly, although you shouldn't have much problems with underscores.

Answer (score 1):

I think is a bug in sfRoute.class.php. The line 683:
'variable_regex' => '[\w\d_]+'

in PHP \w "Matches any alpha numeric character including underscore (_)" and the last underscore matches the same. I've tried to change this line for:
'variable_regex' => '[\A-Za-z\d]+'

And now I can use underscore as a separator.

I haven't tested this very much. I don't know if this crashes any other features (surely), but maybe this is the line where the Symfony programmers can start this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in symfony.

I have made a test which failed and submitted a [bug report](http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/8692) with the test to the symfony project